# RabbitMQ - How to handle further message processing with Consumer.handleDelivery

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, consumer

in my program, I am receiving a message from an Exchange. I created my own Consumer and override the handleDelivery method.

How can I pass the message onto another class and process the message cleanly?

Right now I have a listener with an onNewMessage method that is called inside the handleDelivery method. The problem I see with this is that the handleDelivery method is not exited until I finish processing the message (or at least the onNewMessage method).

Can you help me with this issue?

Many Thanks!

Edit - added Code:

```
@Override
public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {

    eventMsg.add(properties.getHeaders().get("filePath"));
    eventMsg.add(body);

    if(listener != null) {
        listener.onEventConsumed(eventMsg);
    }
}



public void onEventConsumed(List<Object> eventMsg) {
        byte [] evtPayload = (byte[]) eventMsg.get(1);
        String filePath = eventMsg.get(0).toString();
        String jobToStart = config.getJobGlossary().get(filePath);
        activeJobs.add(new Job(filePath, evtPayload, jobToStart, amqpFactory, config));

    }
```

And the processing goes on inside the Job Object.

Comment: Can you add some of your code?

Comment: I added the handleDelivery method and the event that is executed by the listener.

Comment: Do you think onEventConsumed is executed asynchronous?

Comment: I don't know what is is you are trying to achieve.